# calculating person age showes the same number everytime

Tags: c#

i want to calculate someone's age by entering he's birthday and show it in textbox but it keeps giving me the same exact age which is 2013    and i dont know why any help would be  appreciated  , here is the code

```
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";


        int orderID = 0;

        orderID = Int32.Parse(textBox74.Text);

        int bday = orderID;



        DateTime B_DAY = new DateTime(bday);
        DateTime Today = DateTime.Today;
        int age2 = Today.Year - B_DAY.Year;
        if(B_DAY > Today.AddYears(-age2))
            age2-- ;


        string theage = age2.ToString();


        this.textBox70.Text = theage;
```

Comment: Int32.Parse(textBox74.Text); Are you trying to parse a date in string format to an int?

Comment: This is *amazingly* confusing code for how little of it there is.  When you step through this in a debugger, what are the runtime values?  Where does your calculation produce a different result from what you expect?  It's difficult to even determine what you're *trying* to do by reading the code.

Comment: At a guess, he's entering in a text box a date formatted like "November 16th, 1989" (or it could be 16th November, it makes no difference) and converting that to a DateTime by way of an int. Of course since C# DateTimes are "the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000" that's basically the zero date, which leads to the reported behaviour.

Comment: @NahuelI. I think this bit `Int32.Parse(textBox74.Text);` is to parse ID rather than a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing with so much of confusions you can use it simply,

```
DateTime drid2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox74.Text);
DateTime drid3 = DateTime.Now;
int yy1 = Math.Abs(drid1.Year - drid2.Year);
textBox70.Text = yy1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your code is unclear and making confusion here how you can calculate  the age  in a tricky way

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime  birthDate = new DateTime(1969,12,25);
            int age = (int) ((DateTime.Now - birthDate).TotalDays/365); 
        }
```